# Android Studio ui not effect

Tags: android, android-studio

android studio 2.2.x
gradle version is 2.14.1
jdk 8
compile sdk version is 23.0.3 or 24.0.3 or 25.0.0

I change textview's text and it don't effect by instant run.

Comment: please add code here

Answer (score 0):

Simple Fix: Choose API 21 by clicking on the little green android head. (above your screen design preview)